# Hive SQL: Select all rows before event

Tags: sql, window, hiveql, row-number

In Hive, I have the following data

```
sess,person,type,number
a   mary    I   1
a   mary    I   2
a   mary    V   3
a   mary    V   4
b   mary    I   1
b   mary    V   2
b   mary    C   3
a   john    I   1
a   john    I   2
a   john    V   3
a   john    V   4
b   john    I   1
b   john    V   2
b   john    C   3
```

How do I select everything for each person and session up to and including the first type=V? The output should look like

```
sess,person,type,number
    a   mary    I   1
    a   mary    I   2
    a   mary    V   3
    b   mary    I   1
    b   mary    V   2
    a   john    I   1
    a   john    I   2
    a   john    V   3
    b   john    I   1
    b   john    V   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when type = 'V' then number end) over (partition by session, person order by number) as min_aid
      from t
     ) t
where min_aid is null or number <= aid;
```